# Prove that $\sum_{cyc} \frac{x+1}{y+1} \leq \sum_{cyc} \frac{x-1}{y-1}$ for $x,y,z \in \mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

> Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb R$ such that $x,y,z>1$. Then prove that
> $$\frac{x+1}{y+1}+\frac{y+1}{z+1}+\frac{z+1}{x+1} \leq \frac{x-1}{y-1}+\frac{y-1}{z-1}+\frac{z-1}{x-1}$$

What I was trying to do is as follows :

WLOG, let us assume that $x\geq y\geq z$
Then, I separated the individual terms and solve the inequality.

While it worked for the first two cases. When I went over to the third case, that is,

$\frac{z+1}{x+1}\leq\frac{z-1}{x-1}$

I arrived at a contradiction as the above inequality surmounted to hold iff $x\leq z$

Now, I am stuck and I am not able to understand what should be done. Please help me out.